# VirtualBox is giving me only 32bit option for system installation but I have 64 bit processor

Tags: linux, virtualbox, 64bit, 32bit

I have a problem. I have a 64bit processor (Intel i7) and my VirtualBox does not recognize it. The error is like "you do not have 64 bit processor found". In the options while choosing the distribution, you can choose only 32 bit versions. My host system is 64 bit Kali and I don't see how to debug this problem. Reinstalling does not help - I tried.

Comment: Did you enable VT-x in your hosts system's BIOS?

Comment: You may have a 64-bit CPU, but is the _host_ operating 64-bit?  This is required for 64-bit _guest_ OSs.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a circa 2000 host computer, the CPU is most certainly 64-bit. The fact that you are running a 64-bit OS rules out you having a 32-bit CPU. There are two reasons you might face this problem:

1. The Virtualization technology is not enabled. To solve this, go into the Setup of the host computer (by hitting F1/F2/Del, depending on your computer) when it boots up. Somewhere there, you should be able to find a place to enable it (it should be named like VTxxx).
2. You might need to enable PAE (or something like that) before launching the installation process of the Guest OS. It will be in Settings of the VM that are setting up.